# Интересный эффект на сайте Яндекса

Tags: jquery, яндекс-поиск

Недавно заметил прикольную вещь на сайте [Яндекс](http://www.yandex.ru), наведите мышкой под надписью "Яндекс - Найдется все" и Вы увидите как вся страница сразу преображается... Как думаете это реализовано у яндексоидов? В принципе, это реально сделать на `jQuery`, но думаю, что они используют что-то самописное. А что думаете Вы?

П. С. Чтобы эффект работал нужно быть не залогиненым на сайте Яндекса. Причем эффект работает отлично при любом разрешении экрана...

Comment: ничего не увидел

Comment: ЧЯДНТ?

Кстати, они jQuery таки юзают. И БЭМ

Comment: Не у кого кроме вас такое не наблюдается :)

Comment: нужно мышкой немного ниже, на банер "заведи почту"

Comment: Да, правильно, нужно навести мышкой на баннер "Заведи почту"

Comment: @eprivalov1, не суть важно, поверим наслово, что так что-то происходит. В общем, @neoascetic ответил на ваш вопрос. Кроме того, Wappalyzer так же показывает, что jQuery используется. Да и какая разница? По сути это всё JS или же от него происходящие фреймворки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это делается на css =))
Автор, открой фаербаг и обрати внимание на добавление класса к `body` при наведении на этот баннер.
Добавлется класс: `b-domik_overlay_enabled_yes`,
а также дергаются теги с классами `b-domik__overlay b-domik__overlay-fade-in` и `b-domik__overlay-text b-domik__overlay-fade-in`, у которых `z-index` просто выше, чем у всего остального на странице :)